# Show that the equation of conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ can we written as $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic not equal to $2$. We define a conic $C$ to be a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^2_K$ defined by a homogeneous equation of degree $2$. I need to show that the equation of $C$ can be written as $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$$ for some $a,b,c\in K $ and some basis $(x,y,z)$. I have two different proof ideas:

**Idea 1.** I have seen many places (see for example *"Elementary Geometry of Algebraic Curves"* by Gibson, Chapter 5.2) that the equation of the conic has the general form
$$
ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c = 0
$$
when viewed as an affine variety in the affine plane (not projective plane). I guess I'll need to show that this is true myself, as this is not our definition of a conic.
Furthermore, the equation can be represented in terms of the matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & h & g \\
h & b & f \\
g & f & c 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If we write $v=(x,y,1), $ then the equation can be written as $$vAv^T = 0.$$ Now if one can show that $A$ is diagonalizable, then we will have shown that such a basis exists. But I don't know any general result that we can use to say this. Maybe one could use the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and deduce that this polynomial has $3$ distinct roots (and hence $A$ has $3$ distinct eigenvalues, and is hence diagonizable). But this approach doesn't seem very straightforward, as our matrix $A$ is very general.

**Idea 2.** For the second proof idea I wanted to use the fact that there is a one-to-one correspondence between cones in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ and projective varieties in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

A projective conic $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ can be written as the zero locus of a single homogeneous polynomial $f\in K[x,y,z]$ of degree $2$, i.e. $C=V_p(f)$.

We have from the course notes [Gathmann 2014 Example 7.6.(d)](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/de/alggeom.php) that a projective conic is isomorphic to $V_p(xz-y^2)$ or $V_p(yz-x^2)$, and every projective conic is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. The affine part is isomorphic to $V_a(y-x^2)$ or $V_a(xy-1)$.

I was thinking that if I can show that $$K[x,y]/(y-x^2)\cong K[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)\cong K[x,y]/(xy-1),$$ then we can use the one-to-one correspondence and get $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong C\cong V_p(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

But I'm not sure about this strategy either, or how one would establish such an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea 1 should work with a couple of modifications: the equation you have is the affine part in the chart $z = 1$, to get the projective conic you should take the homogenization
$$ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2hxy + 2gxz + 2fyz = uAu^T$$
for $u = (x, y, z)$ and the same $A$. Second, you don't want diagonalizable in the sense of $PAP^{-1}$ being diagonal, but $PAP^T$ being diagonal for some invertible $P$ (and then the required basis is given by $uP$). In fact for any *symmetric* $n \times n$ matrix $A$, away from characteristic $2$ you can always find a $P$ such that $PAP^T$ is diagonal: find a vector $x$ such that $x^T A x \ne 0$ (otherwise $x^T A y = \frac12((x + y)^T A (x + y) - x^T A x - y^T A y) = 0$ for all $x, y$, so $A = 0$) and inductively "diagonalize" $A$ restricted to $\{y \mid x^T A y = 0\}$.

Since the question is about $n = 3$, which is pretty small, you can also just directly do the algebra on the expression $uAu^T$, this is a form of completing the square, as mentioned by @ancientmathematician.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know if it is possible to find a matrix $P$ such as you describe, for any $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with entries in $\textit{any}$ field $K$, with characteristic not $2$ (and not only $K=\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: @slowpoke When the characteristic is not $2$ doesn't the Lagrange completion of squares method not do exactly that?

Comment: @slowpoke sorry, added complex by accident. Fixed and added the induction step to show where you need to divide by $2$.

Comment: @ronno I see :) I'm still a bit unsure about the induction argument: do we do the induction on the size of $A$ - take n=1 and then show it holds for all n - or induction on the size of $x$ - take $x$ to be size $1\times n$ s.t. $x^TAx$ is diagonal, and then show there exist a $x'$ of size $2\times n$ s.t. $x'^TAx'$ is diagonal too (and so on). What do you mean when you write: 'inductively "diagonalize" $A$ restricted to $\{y|x^TAy=0\}$'?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for the hint! I'll try to look into this method

Comment: @slowpoke Yes, the induction is on the size of $A$. The subspace $W = \{y \mid x^T A y = 0\}$ is $n-1$ dimensional, so there is an $(n - 1) \times (n - 1)$ matrix, say $A'$, such that if $y, z \in W$ is written as $(n-1) \times 1$ vectors $y'$, $z'$ in terms of a basis of $W$ then ${y'}^T A' z' = y^T A z$. Now by induction there is a choice of basis for $W$ in which $A'$ is diagonal. Appending $x$ to this basis gives a basis of $K^n$ in which $A$ will be diagonal.

Comment: It may be useful to think of $A$ as the symmetric bilinear form $\phi(x, y) =x^T A y$ instead of as a matrix. Every quadratic form away from characteristic $2$ is of the form $x \mapsto \phi(x, x)$. Symmetric bilinear forms can always be diagonalized, by induction on the dimension of the vector space, and the induction step restricts $\phi$ to the kernel of $y \mapsto \phi(x, y)$.